# Convert CString to UINT ID

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

I have some ID in MFC application, e.g.:

```
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1002
```

And I have some functions in APP, using this ID, e.g.:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)->SetWindowPos(NULL,cx-750,cy-100,90,40,NULL);
```

Can I convert CString, like "IDC_BUTTON1" to use it dynamically?
I want to do something like this:

```
GetDlgItem(_converted_string_)->SetWindowPos(NULL,cx-750,cy-100,90,40,NULL);
```

Conversion (atoi or smth.) from "1002" is not a variant.

Comment: `IDC_BUTTON1` is a symbol, that exists during compilation only. Once the final executable image is generated, there are no traces left behind. So no, there is no way to do what you're asking for. Why would you need that? What is your specific scenario?

Comment: I have a lot of strings in a string table. It will be useful for me to call them like CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(_converted string_)), not CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID))

Comment: Why would a `CString` with the value of a compile-time constant be useful? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because I want to separate resources with texts from code, for localization.  Using this tool: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3711/RC-Localization-Tool-LocalizeRC

Comment: @СергейСоколов you probably misread/misunderstood something in the codeproject article.

Comment: The program from article is very good, and I using it successfully. But in my code, I have a lot of texts. And I want to send them to resource file (to string table). And It will be very useful for me to call them like CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(converted string)), not CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID))

Comment: You've got this backwards. You **should** be using the resource ID, but load the respective (resource-only) DLL based on the selected language. MFC does most of this for you already anyway (see [Localized Resources in MFC Applications: Satellite DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0.aspx)). For a more complete introduction see [Multiple-Language Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx) (applies to MFC just as well).

Comment: IInspectable - thank you, I have read the article about Satellite DLLs. The question is, that I have many situations in my application, that looks smth like: if (field_name="fieldname") {SetColumnText(CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID)))} So, I want to do something like:  if (field_name="fieldname") {SetColumnText(CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(_field_name_converted_to_UINT)))}, so I can store my field names in a string table, may be in satellite dll.

Comment: You need to drop those bad habits, probably picked up from writing too much PHP or JavaScript code. A string is **not** your universal datatype in C++. If you have code that reads `if (field_name=="fieldname")`, get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329) on writing C++ code. That's an anti-pattern right there.

Answer (score 0):

"IDC_BUTTON1" is not a string type.

It is an object like macro.

You can not apply string functions/operations on object like macros.

object like macros are identifiers, which will be replaced by a code fragment (by definition).